# How to use Zend Mail with postfix on ubuntu 9.04

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, postfix-mta

Anyone could send me a link of a tutorial that show how to do it?

i got postfix installed and working.

i think that i need to install zend framework and set the include_path on php.ini. but i can't install zend framework it always return errors.

thanks.

Comment: Can you define zend framework returns install error? All you need to do to install zf is pu it in the library folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

For using a Zend class you don't need to follow any installation process. The only requirement is that the path to the library is included.

```
$path = '/path/to/library';
// $path is where you have the /Zend folder
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Then you can `include('Zend/Mail.php')` and call the class.